# converting par array to array in scala

Tags: scala-2.10

How can we convert `ParArray[(Double, Double, Double, Double, Double)]` to `Array[(Double, Double, Double, Double, Double)]`

I have to do this as part of creating the data frame using `sc.parallelize(Array[(Double,...)])`

Apart from hardcoding (like below) is there any other way?
`for(x1 <- 0 until a.length){
          new_a(x1)(0) = a(x1)._1
          new_a(x1)(1) = a(x1)._2
          new_a(x1)(2) = a(x1)._3
          new_a(x1)(3) = a(x1)._4
          new_a(x1)(4) = a(x1)._5
      }`

Answer (score 1):

See http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/conversions.html#converting-between-sequential-and-parallel-collections

`val a: ParArray[(Double, Double, Double, Double, Double)] = ???
val rdd = sc.parallelize(a.seq)`